# Blender Export to X3D Texture/Material Capability

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I'm using Blender as a primary part of a workflow that ends with an X3D model.

So far, for geometry and basic (very basic) materials applied to faces, I'm having no issues getting the X3D I expect.

When getting models off of Blend Swap or wherever, they often have very sweet texturing which, to this point, I have been unable to get out to X3D. I understand that Blender's capability ceiling is much higher than what X3D can do, but I'm looking for the lowest common denominator in this aspect.

The Blender manual is incomplete, with a whole lot of "TODO"s, on this matter. The one thing that seemed potentially helpful was the mention of a "Path Mode" for embedded images. Unfortunately, there is no such option in the actual software (2.9) (not on the X3D export dialog anyway). I also read something about "baking" textures, not sure if that's a thing though.

Potential pathing issues aside, I need to find guidelines for what I can and can't get to X3D in the way of texturing and materials, then I can focus my learning efforts appropriately.

I've tried texturing and exporting in every way I can find within Blender. Obviously, there are thousands of options for the several texturing techniques, and trial and error, other than some very basic examples, is not ideal.

Further, I've exported models using every potentially relevant combination of the export options (to x3d). I can look at the x3d that comes out and even edit it, which I do for each one (Note to anyone at Blender, please include options in the x3d export for not including the background and NavInfo nodes you put in there by default).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: Thanks for the information, unfortunately for me, it's the worst possible news.